# App crashes while calling a function

Tags: android, android-emulator, function-calls

How do i call the function from inside onCreate()...I want to call CreateSharedactionprovider() from oncreate() but the app crashes...Am i not calling the function correctly or missing some arguements

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);           
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();

    CreateSharedactionprovider();
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
public boolean CreateSharedactionprovider(Menu menu){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        // Locate MenuItem with ShareActionProvider
         MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_share);
         // Fetch and store ShareActionProvider
         mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();
         doShare();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: please post your logcat so we can help you more.

Answer (score 2):

CreateSharedActionprovider takes a Menu as argument, but you're calling it without any arguments.  Looks like your Menu is null and you are trying to call findItem on it.

Comment: I  tried using Menu as an arguement too but still nothing....Could you tell me how to do it

Comment: You need to create a menu object and pass it in from onCreate().  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html has a nice overview.

Comment: I read it...Actually the app use camera via Intent and when user takes picture and return to UI of my app I want that shareactionprovider should be available so obviously i want it to be called from onCreate()...How to call the method CreateSharedActionprovider()..Could you give a bit of code please

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm confused.  This has nothing to do with the camera.  On initialization, in onCreate, you need to instantiate your menu.  Then you can pass it to CreatedSharedActionprovider.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html is about as clear as it gets.